# Select only entries from one year

Tags: mysql, date

I just can't figure a way to achieve this.
I basically want to get entries of the same year in the database. The field is a `DATETIME` field, so it's easy to calculate with it.

My problem is that I don't want to specify a year: It should automatically use the year thats closest to now. All dates are in the future, but sometimes there are no more entries left of this year anymore, so it should automatically choose the next one available.

I almost certainly know that there's a solution with conditional statements, but I don't understand the syntax well enough to make it happen. I would love to already have something done, but all I know is that I have to use `INTERVAL`, which works fine when I have a year, but that's not enough for this case.

```
SELECT date
FROM table WHERE 
date > (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Could someone help me out here ?

Comment: Do you wish to select the next calendar year (ie for today, the year starting 1/1/12), or the 12-month period starting today?  Your question seems to ask the former but the code addresses the latter.

Comment: @idoimaging Oh yeah, never noticed that... I actually want to select the next calendar year, true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select ...
From TableName 
where `date` BETWEEN concat(year(now()) + 1, '-01-01')
                 AND concat(year(now()) + 1, '-12-31')
```

For `now() == 2011-12-23` it will return all the rows which date is between `2012-01-01` and `2012-12-31`.

**UPD**: as @Nirmal pointed out in the comments below - when you use `BETWEEN` you should always keep in mind that it incorporates both left and right values. So the query above will include only `Dec 31st, 00:00:00`, literally only one second of a whole day. And this can lead  to some unexpected results if you don't care of such edge case.

Comment: Awesome, I'll just put that into a loop till it finds some rows and I'm good. Thank you so much!! Or maybe you even have an idea how I could create that loop right in mysql ?

Comment: @Dan Surfrider: no, you better do that outside

Comment: Won't this include records matching `2013-01-01` too? I believe the results have to be filtered only until (and including) `2012-12-31`.

Comment: @Nirmal: correct, it will include `2013-01-01 00:00:00`, one second from next date. It is usually better to give to the OP not the complete answer, but the main idea how to implement what he wants

Comment: @zerkms: Given that many have confusions over whether `BETWEEN` will include or exclude the entries that fall in the border, it is appropriate to guide them properly. People are here to learn, and they shouldn't be taught incomplete lessons.

Comment: @Nirmal: unfortunately there are too much people here not to literally learn, but to copy-paste the complete code. But indeed I should have specified that

Comment: @Nirmal: also, I was wrong, it won't include `2013-01-01`, but it will include only one second of the whole `Dec 31st` day

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks for the edit. Yes, I missed to realise it would only include 1 second of 31st Dec. That keeps me on tab now. Good day to you!